# ColorFunctionScaling with ParametricPlot3D & InterpolatingFunctions

Tags: plotting, color

Part of [this recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143794/6358) involves coloring a `ParametricPlot3D` of three variables from a set of ODEs according to a fourth variable.  I just figured out how to do that using the slot `#4`, but `ColorFunctionScaling->True` doesn't seem to behave properly.

First, solve the ODEs:

```
nsp = 4;

{r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]} = {1, 0.72, 1.53, 1.27};
{k[1], k[2], k[3], k[4]} = {1, 1, 1, 1};
amat = {{1, 1.09, 1.52, 0}, {0, 1, 0.44, 1.36}, {2.33, 0, 1, 0.47}, {1.21, 0.51, 0.35, 1}};
Do[a[i, j] = amat[[i, j]], {i, nsp}, {j, nsp}];

eqns = Table[x[i]'[t] ==
  r[i]*x[i][t]*(1 - Sum[a[i, j]*x[j][t]/k[i], {j, nsp}]), {i, nsp}];
ics = Table[x[i][0] == 0.1, {i, nsp}];
unks = Table[x[i], {i, nsp}];

tmax = 10000;
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, unks, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
```

It looks good with `ColorFunctionScaling->False`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[1][t], x[2][t], x[3][t]} /. sol], {t, 100, tmax}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2", "x3"}, PlotPoints -> 400, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors", x[4][#4] /. sol] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but totally weird with `ColorFunctionScaling->True`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[1][t], x[2][t], x[3][t]} /. sol], {t, 100, tmax}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2", "x3"}, PlotPoints -> 400, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors", x[4][#4] /. sol] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see what it should look like by manually applying our own scaling directly to the `ColorFunction`:

```
max = NMaximize[{x[4][t] /. sol, 0 < t < tmax}, t, Method -> "RandomSearch"][[1]];
min = NMinimize[{x[4][t] /. sol, 0 < t < tmax}, t, Method -> "RandomSearch"][[1]];

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[1][t], x[2][t], x[3][t]} /. sol], {t, 100, tmax}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2", "x3"}, PlotPoints -> 400, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors", (x[4][#4] - min)/(max - min) /. sol] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Bug or user error? :) v11.1 on MacOS.

Comment: "...but totally weird with `ColorFunctionScaling -> True`" - not really; per the docs, values rescaled to $[0, 1]$ are what get fed to the `ColorFunction`, instead of values in $[100,10000]$.

Comment: @J.M. I expected the `x[4][#4] /. sol` would be scaled to $[0,1]$ not the `#4`, to match my last graph.  ??

Comment: You'd think that, but indeed it is the `t`-values (`#4`) that get scaled. To convince yourself, try catching the values being used: `ColorFunction -> ((Echo[#4]; ColorData["SunsetColors", x[4][#4] /. sol]) &)`

Comment: @J.M. So "user error" it is -- although I'd maintain that this is a weird design choice.  Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler, but hopefully equally illustrative example:

```
{ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
                  ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
                  PlotLabel -> "w/ scaling"], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
                  ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
                  PlotLabel -> "w/o scaling"]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: circles colored with and without scaling]

Recalling that `Hue[]` is $1$-periodic, note that the circle on the left is colored by the color wheel exactly once, corresponding to an internal rescaling of the parameter to $[0,1]$, which is, coincidentally, `Hue[]`'s primary domain. The figure on the right, however, feeds the unscaled ($[0,2\pi]$) parameter values to `Hue[]`, and this is manifested in the repeated bands of color.

Comment: Thanks!  My naive thought was that `ColorFunctionScaling` would scale according to whatever function `#4` is wrapped in (in my case `x[4][#4]/.sol`).  Now I see that it would be ambiguous what exactly the proper function to scale by would be, so its better to just do it manually.